# Spark: Can I compress bytes before saving it to sequence files?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Currently, I'm using

```
map(m => (NullWritable.get() -> new  BytesWritable(m.toByteArray))).saveAsSequenceFile(path, Some(classOf[SnappyCodec]))
```

1) I'd like to get the size of each compressed `byteArray`, write the size first and then write the compressed event.

Is it possible to compress each block of `byteArray` before saving it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
map(m => (m.toByteArray.length -> new  BytesWritable(m.toByteArray))).saveAsSequenceFile(path, Some(classOf[SnappyCodec]))
```